# OpenStack how to route 2 subnet of the same Network

Tags: networking, routes, openstack-neutron

I'm relatively new to Openstack and I cannot find how to route 2 subnets of the same Network.

My topologie is the following :
1. 1 Network,
2. 2 subnets in Network. sub1 (192.168.10.0/24) and sub2 (192.168.20.0/24)

An instance in first sub1 cannot see another instance in sub2.

Q1 : is this normal ? Why are subnet not routed by default ?

I try to add router but router is only possible between an internal Network and a Public Network, but not between subnets.

Q2 : So what is the best solution to communicate between 2 instances in 2 subnets of the same Network ?

Many thank's in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after some tries, I finally find a solution and I want to share it with you.

First, as said by Ron above a router is not necessary a gateway to public networks.

For a precision, I want to have only one network with subnets and not 2 networks.

The solution is to have a router with an interface on each subnet **AND** to add routing information on each subnet using 'host_routes' features.

A Heat stack doing this is the following:

```
  subnet_public:
    type: OS::Neutron::Subnet
    properties:
      name: PublicSubnet
      cidr: 192.168.11.0/24
      network: { get_resource: network_public }
      allocation_pools: [ { "start" : '192.168.11.1', "end" : '192.168.11.253'}]
      dns_nameservers: [ 'xx.xx.xx.xx', ...]
      enable_dhcp: True
      gateway_ip: 192.168.11.254
      host_routes: [ { 'destination' : '192.168.12.0/24', 'nexthop' : '192.168.11.254'}, { 'destination' : '192.168.13.0/24', 'nexthop' : '192.168.11.254'}]
      ip_version: 4
      # tenant_id: { get_param: tenantId }
  subnet_appli:
    type: OS::Neutron::Subnet
    properties:
      name: ApplicationSubnet
      cidr: 192.168.12.0/24
      network: { get_resource: network_public }
      allocation_pools: [ { "start" : '192.168.12.1', "end" : '192.168.12.253'}]
      dns_nameservers: [ 'xx.xx.xx.xx', ...]
      enable_dhcp: True
      gateway_ip: 192.168.12.254
      host_routes: [ { 'destination' : '192.168.11.0/24', 'nexthop' : '192.168.12.254'}, { 'destination' : '192.168.13.0/24', 'nexthop' : '192.168.12.254'}]
      ip_version: 4
      # tenant_id: { get_param: tenantId }
  subnet_database:
    type: OS::Neutron::Subnet
    properties:
      name: DatabaseSubnet
      cidr: 192.168.13.0/24
      network: { get_resource: network_public }
      allocation_pools: [ { "start" : '192.168.13.1', "end" : '192.168.13.253'}]
      dns_nameservers: [ 'xx.xx.xx.xx', ...]
      enable_dhcp: True
      gateway_ip: 192.168.13.254
      host_routes: [ { 'destination' : '192.168.11.0/24', 'nexthop' : '192.168.13.254'}, { 'destination' : '192.168.12.0/24', 'nexthop' : '192.168.13.254'}]
      ip_version: 4
      # tenant_id: { get_param: tenantId }
  #
  # Router
  router_nat:
    type: OS::Neutron::Router
    properties:
      name: routerNat
      admin_state_up: True
      external_gateway_info: { "network": 'ext-net' }
  gateway_itf:
    type: OS::Neutron::RouterInterface
    depends_on: [ network_public, subnet_public, router_nat ]
    properties:
      router_id: { get_resource: router_nat }
      subnet: { get_resource: subnet_public }
  router_appli_itf:
    type: OS::Neutron::RouterInterface
    depends_on: [ network_public, subnet_appli, router_nat ]
    properties:
      router_id: { get_resource: router_nat }
      subnet: { get_resource: subnet_appli }
  router_database_itf:
    type: OS::Neutron::RouterInterface
    depends_on: [ network_public, subnet_database, router_nat ]
    properties:
      router_id: { get_resource: router_nat }
      subnet: { get_resource: subnet_database }
```

Comment: A more explicit document is here : http://xuhanp.tumblr.com/post/107088879052/openstack-neutron-subnet-extra-routes-usage

Answer (score 2):

For one network to talk to a different network, you need a router. I don't know where you got the idea that routers only route between public and private networks; to the router, they are simply two different networks.

You have two networks: `192.168.10.0/24` and `192.168.20.0/24`. For either network to communicate with the other network, you need at least one router in between them, A single router is the simplest since it will not involve routing protocols or statically defined routes.

Comment: Thank's for your answer but I want to route between 2 subnet of 1 network (and not between 2 subnet of 2 networks). By the way, you are right, a router is not only for routing with public subnet and is the solution with the addition of host_routes. Cf. full answer above.